# Extending native element click event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, prototype

The jsbin : http://jsbin.com/weqitiwe/1/

Most coders around the world avoid extending a native Javascript object, but it always fun to work out of the rules.

Some of the *new* native method works, but the `click` event doesn't work. Here is sample code (sorry if it was stupid):

```
Element.prototype.click = function(action) {
    this.addEventListener('click', action, false);
    return this;
}
```

the html : `<div id="the_id">click me</div>`

Then use it:

```
var elm = document.getElementById('the_id');
function say() {
    alert('hi');
}
elm.click(say);
```

The goal is just to be able to use `elm.click(the_function);` as well as `elm.addEventListener('click', the_function, false);`

Any help is appreciated! :),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your new method `click` conflicts with the [`HTMLElement.click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click) existing method (used to programatically trigger a click on an element).

HTML elements inherit from [`HTMLELement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), which in turn inherits from [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element). When you create `click` on `Element` and try to fire it on a HTML element, it is never seen because `HTMLElement.click` overrides it.

Use a different method name it it will work:

```
Element.prototype.click2 = function(action) {
    this.addEventListener('click', action, false);
    return this;
}

...

elm.click2(say);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KJ5RL/)**

Comment: Hi @MrCode ,
Thanks for answering the question. Yes, the `click2` method should solve the problem. But, is it better to just make `HTMLElement.prototype.click` than `Element.prototype.click2` ?

Comment: Well you can override `HTMLElement.prototype.click` but you will be overriding the existing `click` method, which has a different purpose. It's OK for fun/exercise but not recommended for real usage because it can make for some strange bugs (if someone tried to trigger a click with `.click`).

Comment: Even if you manage to make your implementation beautiful and bug-free, the coder who inherits your work will most likely hunt you down and kill you if you modify native prototypes default behaviours.